# Empty Bokeh Plot

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to plot data from my DataFrame using bokeh and plot is always empty. Below is my function.

```
def statplot(stats_df,plotname):
    try:
        source_df = ColumnDataSource(data=stats_df.sort_values(by=['log_time']))
        print(source_df.data)

        output_file(plotname,'General Statistics')

        datetime_tick_formats = {
                key: ["%a %b %d %H:%M:%S"]
                for key in ("seconds", "minsec", "minutes", "hourmin", "hours", "days")}

        hover1 = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Date','@log_time{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'),('Value','@PrivateMem')],formatters = {'@log_time':'datetime'})

        p1 = figure(title="PrivateMemory MB",plot_width=800, plot_height=400,x_axis_type="datetime")
        p1.xaxis.axis_label="Time"
        p1.yaxis.axis_label="MB"
        p1.xaxis.formatter = DatetimeTickFormatter(**datetime_tick_formats)
        p1.line(x='log_time',y='PrivateMem',source=source_df,line_width=2,color="red",legend_label='Private Memory')

        p1.add_tools(hover1)

        plot = gridplot([p1],ncols=1)
        save(plot)
```

I have the print source.data to verify if my ColumnDataSource has any values and it looks like it does. Below is the sample data

```
{'index': array([ 550,  551,  552, ..., 1658, 1659, 1660]), 'log_time': array(['2021-02-19T17:08:27.000000000', '2021-02-19T17:10:59.000000000',
       '2021-02-19T17:11:59.000000000', ...,
       '2021-02-24T08:33:38.000000000', '2021-02-24T08:34:38.000000000',
       '2021-02-24T08:35:38.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]'), 'PrivateMem': array([' 33', ' 67', ' 72', ..., ' 91', ' 90', ' 90'], dtype=object), 'PagedMem': array([' 33', ' 67', ' 72', ..., ' 91', ' 90', ' 90'], dtype=object), 'ThreadCount': array([' 36', ' 54', ' 49', ..., ' 44', ' 45', ' 45'], dtype=object), 'HandleCnt': array([' 1134', ' 2214', ' 2232', ..., ' 2498', ' 2488', ' 2498'],
      dtype=object)}
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong in function that is preventing the values to be plotted?

Comment: Looks OK at a glance. Are there any messages in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: @bigreddot I see a message in the console which reads "bokeh could not set initial ranges"

Comment: Also I am converting my log_time column to datetime. So not sure why else this is failing.
stats_df['log_time'] = pd.to_datetime(stats_df['log_time'])

Comment: @bigreddot I figured out the issue. It is the values in columns I have. I am parsing using regex and the list out of which I built the DataFrame was having a space before the value - [' 44',' 65',' 78']. I removed the spaces and now I have the plot!

Comment: Great! Would appreciate if you self-answer and self-accept the solution, or delete the question, to keep the `[bokeh]` tag tidy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with values in the df with space. Once we removed the space in the values Bokeh was able to plot without any issues.